# Setting innodb_flush_method to O_DIRECT on Centos 7.8

Tags: mysql, centos7

I have read that you should set innodb_flush_method to O_DIRECT in MySQL to avoid double buffering. I have also read that you should not use tmpfs for the tmpdir, because that will disable AIO.

While researching these claims, I found that Centos comes with tmpfs on the tmpdir automatically. I have read that this can create conflicts with O_DIRECT.

One suggested solution is to change the temporary folder for MySQL so that you can use native AIO and avoid double buffering.

Are the claims about double buffering correct?

Or should you just not set innodb_flush_method and let the tmpdir be the default with tmpfs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set innodb_flush_method to O_DIRECT (otherwise you will be churning the page cache by double caching). I don't think having tmpdir=/tmp on tmpfs disables aio entirely for MySQL, but if it does, you are better off making /tmp on a regular file system.

Comment: I understand, thank you. I need to be completely sure though, because this is a live production site. If I enable O_DIRECT and the tmpfs is enabled, I won't get any errors or problems restarting mysqld? And how can I check if it worked? Just look at the RAM-usage in phpMyAdmin before and after?

Comment: It will not fail to start. Startup messages will tell you if there was a problem with aio. You will not see a difference in memory usage, you will see a slower growth of cache usage, which will inevitably always grow to consume all otherwise unused memory. You need to look at top or free, phpmyadmin won't tell you this. This will not save you memory, it will save you a bit of CPU overhead from the kernel managing all that cache memory pointlessly for InnoDB I/O.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks! I'll have to dig deeper into tmpfs, but this at least tells me that it's safe to enable O_DIRECT :)